# Not receiving CloudKit push notifications for Custom Record Zone on the Mac

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, icloud, cloudkit

I've setup a custom zone subscription to receive (silent) push notifications from my custom record zone. Everything works fine on my iOS devices but I'm not able to receive the notifications on my Mac.

To register the notifications I'm registering the notification type in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:NSRemoteNotificationTypeNone];
```

(Tried the other types with the same result)

```
application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
```

is then called with a valid token. Everything seems fine but when the custom zone registers changes, I receive no notification and

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

is not called. I've also tried to set the alert body to an empty string like this:

```
CKNotificationInfo *info = [[CKNotificationInfo alloc] init];
info.alertBody = @"";
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = YES;
```

but it didn't work either. When I set a string as the alert body (and register the appropriate notification type)  I also get a notification with that body in the top right corner but application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: is not called.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try turning on APNS logging as is described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24

Comment: Yes, since the log is too long for a comment, I've made a dropbox link available: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8axvsjb89aew9d6/APNS-log.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same issue on the Mac, iOS seems to work just fine but Mac won't receive push notifications at all from cloudkit.

Comment: I have the exact same question here I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130206/cloudkit-didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-on-the-mac

Any luck with this? It works on iOS but not on Mac. I have already logged a bug with Apple - please do the same else this won't get fixed as it's there in 10.11 Beta 7 as well.

Comment: I have answered @strangetimes question with code which works for me.

Comment: Did you get something more about this? I tried @Mojo66 solution but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: No, @Mojo66 solution didn't work for me neither. The bug still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fixed with macOS Sierra. Working for me now.

Edit:
Oh wow: just noticed that I (!) asked this question 1,5y ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply extracting the correct solution from one of the shared links: If you use a CKNotificationInfo for your alerts, didReceiveRemoteNotification will NOT be called on the Mac until and unless you set CKNotificationInfo.soundName to an empty string! This looks like a bug only in OS X (10.10 & 10.11 so far) but can be worked around by this simple change.

Comment: I'm still not able to receive a notification on the Mac.

My code for the notification info:
`CKNotificationInfo *info = [[CKNotificationInfo alloc] init]; 
info.alertBody = @"";
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = YES;
info.soundName = @"";
info.shouldBadge = NO;`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the correct environment 'development' vs 'production'? If you're testing with an iOS app from TestFLight, it won't work as TestFlight uses Production environment, and on the Mac you can only test with Development.

Comment: Yep, push between and to iOS devices works fine in my development environment.

Comment: I tried this - and it didn't seem to work- but the badge incremented so it seems to be receiving the notifcation but not calling the didReceiveRemoteNotifications

Comment: Why the downvote? I've genuinely left an answer which worked for 10.10 and 10.11 the last I tested it. Apple's possibly fixed the bug (or introduced a new one). I have a working app in production that's gotten around it this way. Testing with iOS will only work if both are set to development OR both are in production. Adhoc / Developer ID apps on Mac don't get push notifications the last I checked.