# CloudKit didReceiveRemoteNotification not called on the Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, icloud, cloudkit, osx-yosemite

I am using the following CKNotification Info and this seems to work fine:

`CKNotificationInfo *note = [[CKNotificationInfo alloc] init];
 note.alertBody = @"Something Happened";
 note.shouldBadge = NO;
 note.shouldSendContentAvailable = NO;`

When something changes on an iOS device, my Mac app receives a Push notification based on a subscription with this notification. However, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never called so I can't process the event. I need to be able to refresh and fetch new changes. How do I do that?

Comment: I had the same issue and even reported it to Apple at the time. At some point the issue just went away. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've finally figured it out. If you use a CKNotificationInfo for your alerts, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will NOT be called on the Mac until and unless you set `CKNotificationInfo.soundName` to an empty string! This looks like a bug only in OS X (10.10 & 10.11 so far) but can be worked around by this simple change.

Comment: Yeah I've read that before. Note though that my sample code is designed for silent push notifications. I'll edit the posting accordingly.

Comment: Sure, but my question specifically mentioned I'm using 'CKNotificationInfo'. By the way, I'm using silent notifications too, simply by providing the notification info an empty title.

Comment: It still won't work for me despite having soundName set to an empty string. I'm on the latest MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` and implementing `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`
should be enough code, and the App ID should include the *Push Notifications* service.

I'm using CloudKit in a cross-platform (iOS/OS X) app to synchronize favorites between devices like so:

```
// OS X specific code
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSApp registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:NSRemoteNotificationTypeNone];// silent push notification!
}

- (void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [self.favCon handleCloudKitNotificationWithUserInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Note the usage of `NSRemoteNotificationTypeNone` which means silent push notification! This is how I set up CloudKit in the FavController class:

```
- (void)getOrCreateFavZoneWithCompletionHandler:(successCompletionHandler)handler {

    // check if FavZone exists op
    __block int createZone = 0;
    CKFetchRecordZonesOperation *fetchRecZonesOp    = [[CKFetchRecordZonesOperation alloc] initWithRecordZoneIDs:@[[FavController favRecordZoneID]]];
    CKModifyRecordZonesOperation *saveRecZoneOp     = [[CKModifyRecordZonesOperation alloc] initWithRecordZonesToSave:nil recordZoneIDsToDelete:nil];
    fetchRecZonesOp.fetchRecordZonesCompletionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *recordZonesByZoneID, NSError *operationError) {
        if (recordZonesByZoneID.count == 0) {// zone doesn't exist
            createZone              = 1;
            CKRecordZone *favZone   = [[CKRecordZone alloc] initWithZoneName:UTXAFavZoneName];
            saveRecZoneOp.recordZonesToSave         = @[favZone];
            NSLog(@"Creating new Zone %@", favZone.zoneID.zoneName);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Zone %@ already exists.", [FavController favRecordZoneID].zoneName);
        }
    };

    // create FavZone op
    saveRecZoneOp.modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock  = ^(NSArray *savedRecordZones, NSArray *deletedRecordZoneIDs, NSError *operationError) {
        [self successCompletionHandler:(savedRecordZones.count == createZone) error:operationError informDelegate:YES handler:handler];
    };

    [saveRecZoneOp addDependency:fetchRecZonesOp];
    [[FavController favDatabase] addOperation:fetchRecZonesOp];
    [[FavController favDatabase] addOperation:saveRecZoneOp];
}

- (void)subscribeToFavChanges:(successCompletionHandler)handler {

    // get current subscription
    [[FavController favDatabase] fetchSubscriptionWithID:UTXAFavConCKSubscriptionID completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
        if (subscription) {
            NSLog(@"using existing subscription: %@", subscription);
            [self successCompletionHandler:YES error:nil informDelegate:NO handler:handler];
        } else {
            CKSubscription *sub = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithZoneID:[FavController favRecordZoneID]
                                                          subscriptionID:UTXAFavConCKSubscriptionID
                                                                 options:0];// "You must specify 0 for this parameter. Zone subscriptions currently do not support any options."
            [[FavController favDatabase] saveSubscription:sub completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"created new subscription: %@ %@", subscription, error);
                [self successCompletionHandler:(error == nil) error:error informDelegate:YES handler:handler];
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

As soon as I add or remove a record on one device, I'll get a notification on all other device, which I handle like so in the FavController class:

```
/// @abstract Handle push notifications sent by iCloud.
/// @discussion App delegates call this method when they receive a push notification through didReceiveRemoteNotification.
///          Currently, only airport favorites produce a PN, it is of type CKNotificationTypeRecordZone.
/// @param userInfo The userInfo dict tied to each push notification.
- (void)handleCloudKitNotificationWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

        [self recursivelyCheckForPreviousCloudKitNotifications];
}


- (void)recursivelyCheckForPreviousCloudKitNotifications {

    CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation *fetchOp    = [[CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation alloc] initWithPreviousServerChangeToken:_defCon.notificationChangeToken];
    __weak CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation *weakOp = fetchOp;

    fetchOp.notificationChangedBlock                = ^(CKNotification *notification) {
            [self handleNotification:notification];
    };

    fetchOp.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = ^( CKServerChangeToken *serverChangeToken, NSError *operationError) {
        NSLog(@"new notification change token: %@", serverChangeToken);
        _defCon.notificationChangeToken = serverChangeToken;
        if (weakOp.moreComing) {
            NSLog(@"more coming!!");
            [self recursivelyCheckForPreviousCloudKitNotifications];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"done handling notification changes.");

        }
    };
    [[FavController favContainer] addOperation:fetchOp];
}



- (void)handleNotification:(CKNotification *)notification {// withCompletionHandler:(successCompletionHandler)handler {

    if (notification.notificationType == CKNotificationTypeRecordZone) {// make sure we handle only zone changes

        CKRecordZoneNotification *noti = (CKRecordZoneNotification *)notification;

        if ([noti.recordZoneID.zoneName isEqualToString:[FavController favRecordZoneID].zoneName]) {
            // received an update for the fav zone
            [self queuedFavUpdateFromCloud];
        } else {
            // received an update for an unknown zone
            NSLog(@"WARNING: received an update for an unknown zone: %@", noti.recordZoneID.zoneName);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: received unknown notification: %@", notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. As I mentioned, I'm talking about CloudKit and automatic push subscription notifications. Apparently this is a known bug.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this bug?

Comment: I've reported it to Apple. It's a well tested and reproducible bug with CloudKit on OS X, all versions.

Comment: The procedure outlined above works for me. If it doesn't work for you because of a bug, then it's not my fault and no reason to downvote.

Comment: The procedure cannot possibly work for you if you are working with CloudKit. I already mentioned that 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' is not called. I'm not talking about normal push notifications, I'm referring to notifications coming from CloudKit. Have you put a breakpoint in 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' to see if it gets called? All other reports say otherwise, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896830/not-receiving-cloudkit-push-notifications-for-custom-record-zone-on-the-mac?lq=1

Comment: I added working code from my cross-device project. You can downvote my answer as long as you want but this code works for and yes, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called!

Comment: On what OS X version are you having CloudKit working? I'm on El Capitan Beta 7 and all the configuration and code is OK (I checked with yours). I don't know what to do.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is an issue only with the beta version of El Capitan.

Comment: I have been unsuccessful in receiving a notification in 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' even on 10.11 GM.

Comment: In your code above I don't see any sign of 'CKNotificationInfo' being used by the way. That's what I'm having issues with.

Comment: As you can see from the line `[NSApp registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:NSRemoteNotificationTypeNone]` I'm using silent push notifications, hence I don not create a `CKNotificationInfo` object in my code.

Comment: In theory this (not using CKNotificationInfo) should work for silent push notifications but it doesn't work for me. Adding a CKNotificationInfo (with empty sound name) doesn't help.

Comment: I'm on 10.11.6 and I can't get didReceiveRemoteNotification to work either

Comment: @EzekielElin although my answer below seems to have been downvoted, it works just fine for me (make sure if you're testing with iOS, both apps are on the same profile: development and production don't mix!)